# DCOS Marathon-LB returns 503

Tags: haproxy, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I deployed application 1 on service port 10101. It's an external facing app with label `HAPROXY_0_VHOST=vhost1.xxx.xxx`. And it works with no problems.

Then I deployed a similar application 2 on service port 10102, with `HAPROXY_1_VHOST=vhost2.xxx.xxx`. I read Marathon-LB's document and this is my understanding of how to deploy 2 apps on different VHOST. However, `curl http://vhost2.xxx.xxx` returns `HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable`.

I confirmed that application 2 is running normally by checking the result from `curl marathon-lb.marathon.mesos:10102` on DCOS master node.

Did I configure VHOST incorrectly? Or something else was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out: the app for vhost2 should be labeled `HAPROXY_0_VHOST=vhost2.xxx.xxx` instead of `HAPROXY_1_VHOST=vhost2.xxx.xxx`. The documentation is note clear here.